# How to get data from table based on part of a value?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize as ORM for node and mysql database. Now I want to get all items from table based on part of value. Example: I look for Guitar it should return: Guitars, Guitar Red 6 strings etc...

```
const getGuitarsName = async name => {
    let rslts= undefined

    try {
        results = await db.Guitars.findAll({
            where: {
                name
            }
        })
    } catch(err) {
        return {success: false}
    }

    return {success: true, rslts}
}
```

also on router I have something like:

```
router.get('/guitar/:gitName', async (req, res) => {
    const gitName = req.params.gitName
    const data = await guitarService.getSingleName(gitName)

    if(!data.success) return responses.throwError(res)

    return responses.throwSuccess(res, data.results)
})
```

so if I use route like localhost/guitar/Guitar Red 6 Strings i got result, but if i try to use localhost/guitar/Guitar i got {"message":"Success","data":[]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `LIKE` keyword to match string that are like the one you pass, with the following key-characters:

- `_` means any character there
- `%` means any 1 or more characters there

Therefore, you are looking for something like this

```
results = await db.Guitars.findAll({
  where: {
    name: {
      [Op.like]: 'Guitar%'
    }
  }
})
```

Moreover, if you are using PostgreSQL, you can use the `ILIKE` (`[Op.ilike]`) operator which is the same as `LIKE`, excepts it is case insensitive. See: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/querying.html

Comment: thanks, but that part: 'Guitar%' is coming from URL, so it should be dynamic, right? in my case that is  const gitName = req.params.gitName

Comment: well replace the string value by the variable, you can even do something like `[Op.like]: '%' + yourVar + '%'`.